# Android RecyclerView Adapter Position is -1

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I am making a todo list app where if I click on an item in a `RecyclerView` a `Dialog` will pop up that lets you edit the name of that task. On some tasks when I accept the changes the app crashes and this stack trace pops up.

```
10-02 15:10:34.801 9701-9701/com.gigstudios.todolist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.gigstudios.todolist, PID: 9701
                                                                       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
                                                                           at com.gigstudios.todolist.RecyclerListAdapter$3$1.onInput(RecyclerListAdapter.java:166)
                                                                           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.onClick(MaterialDialog.java:370)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

This is the line where it crashes because `getAdapterPostion` returns -1:

```
taskList.getTasks().get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setTitle(input.toString().trim());
```

I cant seem to find any pattern on which items crash and why others don't.Here is the full code for the `onBindViewHolder`.

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            //other code




            //edit task
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                            .title(R.string.edit_task)
                            .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)
                            .inputRange(0, 300)
                            .positiveText(R.string.save)
                            .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                            .input(context.getString(R.string.task_title), holder.textView.getText().toString(), new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                                    //Edit Task
                                    taskList.getTasks().get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setTitle(input.toString().trim());
                                    notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                                    //save
                                    save();
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What if you replace `holder.getAdapterPosition()` with `position` (the parameter in the method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I added an onDropListener and in that I just notifyOnDataSetChanged the recyclerview. Then I use the position parameter value that is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

The position is available to your `onBindViewHolder` parameter,try to use that one.

```
 taskList.getTasks().get(position).setTitle(input.toString().trim());
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: That doesn't work. It provides a number but it's almost always the wrong number. That's why iv'e been using getAdapterPosition(). I'm constantly dragging and sorting the items btw

Comment: Can you please show me your adapter class..